# Move specific cells from one tab to another based off non blank data in row

Tags: vba, excel

needing assistance. I have a file where column A-F has data and column H-M has data. I need the code to loop through A-F and copy cells A,C,E and paste them on sheet3, then once it hits the first blank cell in column A, move to column H-M and loop through, copying H,J,K,L and moving it to sheet3 in the fist blank cell after the first loop completes. Below is what I have so far, when I get to last "next cell2" I get an error... Am I on the right track? Any pointers?

```
Sub Test()



 Dim rowCount2 As Long

rowCount2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


Dim rng2 As Range


Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C20:C" & rowCount2)

Dim currentRow As Long
 currentRow = 1


 For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
 If cell2.Value <> "" Then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A" & currentRow)
 currentRow = currentRow + 1
 GoTo NextIteration

 End If
 Next cell2
NextIteration:
 Next cell2

 End Sub
```

Comment: I get error "Compile Error: Next Without For"

Comment: You don't need the `Goto` here, and you've duplicated the line `Next cell2`

Comment: Thanks Tim! Ok, I think Im getting there. I modified the code below. Now it copies everything down to the end of the sheet                        Sub Test()
Dim rowCount2 As Long
rowCount2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C20:C" & rowCount2)
Dim currentRow As Long
currentRow = 1
 For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
 If cell2.Value <> "" Then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows(cell2.Row).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A" & currentRow)
 currentRow = currentRow + 1
 End If
 Next cell2
 End Sub

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I hadn't really read your question fully, and I'm still not sure I'm following exactly what you want to do - do you want A,C and E to go into A,B,C on sheet3?  That's what I'm assuming below.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim shtDest As Worksheet, shtSrc As Worksheet

    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

    CopyUntilBlank shtSrc.Range("C20"), Array("A", "C", "E"), _
                                        shtDest.Range("A1")

    CopyUntilBlank shtSrc.Range("H20"), Array("H", "J", "K", "L"), _
                   shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub

'Starting with "startCell" and continuing as long as there's a value
'  in that cell, copy the cells with columns in "arrCols" over to the
'  destination starting at "destCell"
Sub CopyUntilBlank(startCell As Range, arrCols, destCell As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n
    Do While Len(startCell.Value) > 0
        For i = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
            startCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, arrCols(i)).Copy destCell.Offset(0, i)
        Next i
        Set startCell = startCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Set destCell = destCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this one is doing what the last one was except its not copying the last 2 rows for some reason. However, I only need to copy rows A,C,E from the first set of data and H,J,K,L from the second data set. How would I go about cell2.EntireRow.Copy and instead do cell2.copy cellA1,C1,E1?

Comment: Sub Test()
    Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C20:C" & rowCount2)
    currentRow = 1
    For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            cell2.Offset(0, -1).Copy shtDest.Range("A" & currentRow)
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
    Next cell2
End Sub

Comment: I added the above, can get it to copy one row, but cannot figure out how to have it copy multiple rows then loop to the next set of data... any pointers?